# Visual Studio 2017 can not Debug new asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I installed VS2017 Enterprise on my Windows 10 machine. I created a test core project and hit F5. And I'am keeping getting this error.

The program '[11084] dotnet.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
code:-32000
message:No script for id: 32
The program '[11084] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
The program '[5892] chrome.exe: WebKit' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[10272] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[10272] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

So I can't debug, and can not running. I would be grateful if you could give me any sugetion

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Visual Studio as an administrator?